# Prove that $(ℤ/5ℤ)[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ is not a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm making some exercises to prepare for my ring theory exam:

> Prove that $(ℤ/5ℤ)[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ is not a field.

Comment: You have shown that $x^2 + 2x + 2$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$.  This implies $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 2x + 2)$ is not a field (in fact is not an integral domain)

Comment: You proved that it is not a domain. A field is a domain. Ergo, you have proved that it is not a field.

Comment: Okay, that was easy. Thanks !

Comment: Shall I delete this question ?

Comment: you can answer it yourself :)

Comment: @Jyrki: This is a great idea in general!

Answer (score 3):

In the ring $(ℤ/5ℤ)[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ you have the equality: $$0=X^2+2X+2=X^2+2X-3=(X+3)(X-1)$$

And as $X+3$ and $X-1$ are not zero, $(ℤ/5ℤ)[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ is not a domain. So it is surely not a field. If you have any questions about the steps I take, feel free to comment.

Comment: Can you explain me why $R$ not a domain $⇒$ $R$ not a field ?

Comment: Watch it ; $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ is a field. But $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ is not a field because it is not a domain, because $X^2+2X+2$ admits a non-trivial factorization.

Comment: Integral domains are commutative rings with $1$ in which $a,b \neq 0$ implies $ab \neq 0$. Fields are commutative rings with $1$ in which every non-zero element has an inverse. If $a, b \neq 0$ in a field, then $ab$ is a unit because $ab(b^{-1}a^{-1}) = a(bb^{-1})a^{-1} = aa^{-1} = 1$, hence $ab \neq 0$, otherwise we would have $1 = 0$, which we suppose not (in the case of fields). Therefore fields are integral domains.

Comment: Yes I can ! I'm glad you ask this question Kasper. We are going to prove the contrapositive. Suppose $R$ is a field. Let $x≠0$ and $y$ such that $xy=0$. Then $x$ is a unit. So $zx=1$. Now we get $$0=z⋅xy=z(xy)=(zx)y=1⋅y=y$$

So there exist no $y≠0$ such that $xy=0$. Therefore $R$ is a domain.

Comment: Uh... did I just see Kasper talk to himself? Am I crazy?

Comment: Above you would say that $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ is not a domain? @Kasper

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Maybe I'm a little bit crazy ^^

Comment: @Henfe I proof that if $R$ is a field, then $R$ is a domain. So if $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ is not a domain, then $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ is not a field.

Comment: certainly, but in: "And as $X+3$ and $X−1$ are not zero, $(ℤ/5ℤ)$ is not a domain. So it is surely not a field. If you have any questions about the steps I take, feel free to comment".  You would say that $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)[X]/(X^2 + 2X + 2)$ is not a domain? instead of $(ℤ/5ℤ)$

Comment: @Henfe Yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a $0$ in front of your equality? The polynomial doesn't vanish identically.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I'm not sure what you mean, but $X^2+2X+2=0$ in $(ℤ/5ℤ)[X]/(X^2+2X+2)$ right ?